# Cutting/Pasting Data from column B to first empty cell in Column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have just one worksheet that has 6 columns and 10 rows. So the Range of my table is A1:F10 which has 60 cells.

I simply need to cut the data from column B and paste it into the first empty cell in column A. Then, I need it to do the same with columns C - F. Eventually I want to have only one column (Column A) that is 60 rows deep.

```
Sub Move_Columns()
    Range("B1:B10").Copy Destination:=Range("A11")
    Range("C1:C10").Copy Desitnation:=Range("21")
    ' this would continue until columns B-F were copied in column A
End Sub
```

The problem is that this code only copies the data over. I need it removed once it has been copied. I'm also sure there is a much more efficient way to write the code so that I don't have to keep repeating the ranges.

I wish I knew how to write the code so that Excel will automatically cut and paste the data from each column into the first empty row in column A.

Would the For Each Statement be a good idea to add in there?

Comment: Nice question for your first one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make this code, and put some comments to help you to understand.

```
Sub MoveAllInFirstColumn()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'finds the last column
    For i = 2 To lastCol ' foreach columns except first
        Dim lastRow As Integer
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get the lastrow of current column
        Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row, i)).Cut Cells(lastRow + 1, 1) 'cut and paste the current column to the first column
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my goodness!!!! You just saved my life!!!!!!! Seriously I don't know how to thank you enough! How do I upvote and accept the answer? (I'm sorry to be so ignorant, but this is my first time). Actually, I tried to click the up arrow and it would not let me because I don't have a solid reputation yet? Still not seeing where to accept it though.

Comment: Thank you! I have successfully accepted your answer.                                                      Although now I am trying to use your code on a larger scale excel sheet. When I run it the first time, about half of my columns are cut and copied into column A. Then, I delete those columns and try to run it again to get the remaining cells to copy over but it does nothing. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: I tried opening a new work book and copying/pasting my data into the new workbook and it still does not work. I'm not sure why.......

Comment: Is there any error? An overflow error maybe?
My code is assuming that the first cell of columns have to be filled. Do you have columns with first row empty?

Comment: @Jessica240 If my previous comment didn't help you, upload your file (or a sample) somewhere and give the link.

Comment: I got it to work. I think what happened was that the first cell was empty. When I fixed that it worked again. Your help really made my day. I could not have finished my project without you. I hope one day I can be as good as you so I can help others and pass it on.

Answer (score -1):

To continue with what you have:

```
Sub Move_Columns()
  Range("B1:B10").Copy Destination:=Range("A11")
  Range("B1:B10").ClearContents
  Range("C1:C10").Copy Desitnation:=Range("A21")
  Range("C1:C10").ClearContents
  ' this would continue until columns B-F were copied in column A
End Sub
```

An alternative with some looping

```
Sub Move_Columns()
Dim StartCol as Integer
Dim EndCol as Integer
Dim StartRow as Integer
Dim EndRow as Integer
Dim CurRow as Integer
Dim i as Integer
Dim DestCol as integer

DestCol = 1
StartCol = 2
EndCol = 6
StartRow = 1
EndRow = 10

CurRow = StartRow
for I = StartCol to EndCol
  'Range(cells(i, StartRow),cells(i, EndRow).Copy Destination:=Range(DestCol,CurRow)
  'Range(cells(i, StartRow),cells(i, EndRow).ClearContents
  Range(cells(StartRow, i), cells(EndRow, 1)).Copy Destination:=Range(DestCol, CurRow)
  Range(cells(StartRow, i),cells(EndRow,i)).ClearContents
  CurRow = CurRow + EndRow
Next
end Sub
```

Comment: OK, down vote. That's cool. You got a comment on what's wrong with it?

Comment: Freeman, when I copied your code into Excel, the 2 lines from the bottom "Range(cells(i, StartRow),cells(i, EndRow).Copy Destination:=Range(DestCol,CurRow)
  Range(cells(i, StartRow),cells(i, EndRow).ClearContents" became highlighted in red. I'm not sure why?

Comment: Two issues: One, I was missing a ")", two, I had the row/col parameters in the wrong order in the `cells()` calls. I commented out the 2 bad rows & replaced them so you can see the difference.

Comment: I wasn't the one who down voted your answer I hope...  I was hovering my mouse over the arrows to see what they meant. I didn't think I clicked one but if I did I'm sorry I definitely did not mean to....

Comment: No sweat. I'd just like to know what whoever it was thought was wrong, so I could improve it. If you clicked it, you'll see the arrow in orange. If so, you can click it again to remove the vote if it's accidental, though, I don't believe you have enough reputation to vote yet.

Comment: No it wasn't me because I don't have the reputation yet. I just checked. But Thank you so much for your help! I was able to get it to work using the other code but I will definitely save this as a good reference!